# Flexbox items going outside container when window is too short, and sidebar not staying at bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to make a simple flex layout with a header, 2x2 grid of content, then sidebar. It is supposed to move the sidebar to the bottom of the screen when the width of the window is smaller than a certain size.

Currently, once that size is reached, if you make the height of the window too small then the grid content will overlap the header, but im not sure why. The screen should also just be the size of the view height, but moving the sidebar extends its for some reason.

```css
@media (max-width:960px) {
    .main-screen {
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column-reverse;
      .toolbar {
        padding: 10px;
        height: 90px;
        width: auto;
      }
      .body {
        display: flex;
        .grid {
          flex: 1;
          max-height: 36vh;
        }
        .row1, .row2 {
          flex: 1;
          height: 10%;
          max-width: 100%;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

here is the full code in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poizoni/cf46by7e/31/)

(just drag the window size down to see how grids overlap header)

Answer (score 0):

Good day ^^
I've built this for you. Is this what you're looking for?

```css
*{margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
html{height: 100%; width: 100%;}
body{background-color: lightblue;}

/* Header, Main Content, Nav/Sidebar */
header{background-color: lightgray; height: 50px;}
.Main{background-color: darkblue; display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr 80px;}
nav{background-color: pink; width: 100%; outline: 5px solid white;}

/* Rows */
.Main .Row1, .Main .Row2{display: grid; grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; height: 120px;}
/* Row 1 */
.Main .Row1 .Div1{margin: 5px; background-color: lightgreen;}
.Main .Row1 .Div2{margin: 5px; background-color: forestgreen;}
/* Row 2 */
.Main .Row2 .Div3{margin: 5px; background-color: forestgreen;}
.Main .Row2 .Div4{margin: 5px; background-color: lightgreen;}

/* Smaller Size */
@media (max-width:960px) {
.Main{background-color: blue; grid-template-columns: auto;}
nav{height: 50px;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

<section class="Main">
<div>
    <div class="Row1">
        <div class="Div1">Div1</div>
        <div class="Div2">Div2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row2">
        <div class="Div3">Div3</div>
        <div class="Div4">Div4</div>
    </div>
</div>

<nav>
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>
</nav>
</section>
</body>
```